# what is the difference between AsyncStorage and OnSaveInstanceState android

Tags: java, android, typescript, react-native, memory

I am looking for a way to save state between screen transitions and i found OnSaveInstanceState using native Android and AsyncStorage using React Native and im generally wondering what the difference is and the pros and cons to both

OnSaveInstanceState-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.activity.onsaveinstancestate?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

AsyncStorage-https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think your technical purpose here: `save state between screen transitions`.**

First, i will answer your question *what is the difference between AsyncStorage and OnSaveInstanceState android*.

`OnSaveInstanceState` is a `Lifecycle callbacks` function of `Activity` provided only in android environment.

> Learn more about activity life circle [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

`AsyncStorage` is `an asynchronous, persistent, key-value storage system for React Native` (work with both android & iOS)

its using for difference purpose, in difference side, and `can not compared`. ( Same the way trying to compare `m³` with `km/h` )

**So the answer is their are too difference to be compared**

---

## the way to resolve your technical purpose

If your app build with `react-native` i think [reduxjs](https://redux.js.org) can resolve your problem. It's a `A Predictable State Container for JS Apps`, which can bind with [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to take offline storage effect.

> reduxjs is easy to learn. So hope it can help you.